# Creating Eclipse RCP Toolbar With Action

Tags: text, eclipse-rcp, toolbar

I am creating a RCP appliaction Toolbar with Action, I want to set Image as well as MULTI-LINE Text below the image , how can this be done ?

Example -

IMAGE

Search

Result

In the above example, IMAGE is the Icon Image and "Search Result" is the text in multi-line format..